# Reporting Services - Host header and Windows Authentication

Tags: ssrs, reporting

SQL 2016 - Enterprise Edition
Windows 2016
Reporting Services runs on domain account (SPN registered for new host header)

Problem:
When adding a host header in Reporting Services Configuration tool, like reports.server.net,  users need to login to the reporting services.
When I remove the host header and try to connect to hostname/reports I do not get prompted for user/password.

Fact:
 - When i use the default site address http://servername/Reports, before adding a new host header, the site opens up without login prompt

What I've done:

- Created a Host record in DNS for the new address, pointing at reporting services server
- Registered a SPN for the new host record to the service account for reporting service
- Added the new host header to reporting services for web service url and web portal url
- Played around authentication types in the reportserver.config file according to (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/configure-windows-authentication-on-the-report-server?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver13)
- Enabled delegation for the reporting services service account "just in case"

I can't seem to add a host header without beening forced to login, despite above.

Anyone been here?

Comment: What browser are you using to access the report server? Is the host header FQDN the same domain as the machine you're accessing the report server from?

Comment: Any browser. Host Header FQDN is a diffren't domain.

Answer (score 1):

Solved issue by adding new host header address to local intranet site in the browser.